# How to execute an SAP transaction code either using Python or Java?

Tags: java, python-2.7, sap-basis

We would like to execute transaction code `SM04` so that we get users' details.
We want to connect to the underlying API. Could you tell me the Python packages or Java jars?

Comment: Would you like to start SAP GUI with a specific transaction?

Comment: Or do you want the user list from SM04 in your python/java program? If so, you can't connect to the transaction. Instead you need to connect to the underlying API - there are multiple options to do that.

Comment: yes, I want to connect to underlying API and fetch user list from SM04. Could you tell me the python packages or java jars.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question clarified. Here you go:

- Install SAP Java Connector: http://help.sap.com/saphelp_nwpi711/helpdata/en/48/7080a5872c1b5ae10000000a42189c/content.htm
- Write code to execute function module TH_USER_LIST

Comment: I think we can not download the java connector. Because SAP market place is expecting credentials. Could please tell me python package through which we can achieve the same. I already tried pyrfc,sapnwrfc,pysap packages but getting some errors. could you please try any of given python packages and tell me whether you are able to achieve or not.  Else send me the java connector to  my email: gsr7rsg@gmail.com

Comment: I don't know about Python, nor will I send you licensed software via e-mail. But if you can't connect to SAP Marketplace, just ask your SAP system administrator for access.

Comment: Follow instructions in https://sap.github.io/PyRFC/...

Youll need, Python 2.7, then
pip install Cython==0.25.12
Download packages from http://logosworld.com/docs/Python/ or http://logosworld.com/docs/SAP/Connector
and configure some environment variables.
Ill be watching if you have any doubt...